# Problems ordering a linked list in C

Tags: c, list, pointers, swap

I got issues trying to order a linked list from its min to its max, the code is:

```
struct nodo *orderList (struct nodo *p) {

struct nodo *head=p;
struct nodo *min=p;
int *tmp=NULL;

while (min != NULL) {
    p = min;
    // p = p->succ (not necessary i think)
            while (p != NULL) {
                    if (p->info < min->info) {
                            tmp = &min->info;
                            min->info = p->info;
                            p->info = *tmp;
                    }
                p=p->succ;
            }
        min=min->succ;
}
return head;
}
```

The output i get (i use a tested function to create a list with n nodes from input) :

```
Number of elements: 4
insert 4 positive numbers: 
4
3
2
1

1 ->  1 ->  1 ->  1 ->
```

Comment: Please try to debug your code! :)

Comment: It seems like she has tried and has provided output which is a lot more than most people share for problems like this.

Comment: @user1336087 erm.... i dont know how to... im using xcode right now... feeling a bit embarassed bout this :'o

Comment: Note that this "sort" just swaps the info fields of the nodes, it doesn't actually reorder the nodes (by changing the succ (next) pointers (and the head poitner if needed)). This is ok if the nodes only contain one info field, but if the nodes contained multiple fields and you wanted to reorder according to one of the fields, it would be better to reorder the nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code does not swap the data

```
tmp = &min->info;
min->info = p->info;
p->info = *tmp;
```

The third line simply moves the data back to where it was, since `min->info` now contains `p->info`.

You need to swap like this

```
int tmp = min->info;
min->info = p->info;
p->info = tmp;
```

assuming the data type is `int` as you didn't post the `struct`.

Comment: Could use `struct nodo tmp; tmp.info = min->info; min->info = p->info; p->info = tmp.info;` to avoid knowing/maintaining the type of `info` field.

Comment: @chux good play, but I now notice the declaration `int *tmp;`

Answer (score 1):

By using a `int *`, when you swap the info field, you refer to the modified field.

You should declare `tmp` as:

```
int tmp;
```

and adjust your swap code accordingly.

In this way you would **copy the value** of `min->info` before changing it.